# vb/asp.net :getting the actual exception message from a url redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using HtmlUtility to render a url call. It seems that the url it is calling is having some exceptions. problem is the catch is not capturing that exception. it instead captures an Internal Server 500. Does anyone know how can i capture that original error on the url? thank you for your help!

```
Try
    htmlUtility.LoadUrl(request.UrlToGenerateFrom)
catch ex As Exception
    Throw New InvalidEmailRenderException("aspNetEmail failed to load page. URL: " & request.UrlToGenerateFrom, ex)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass on the exception details in the HTML response, you will have to create a new response with the exception information included in it. When you see 'Internal Server error 500', that is because you re-throw your exception in the example code.

If you are using MVC or WebAPI patterns, you can use the [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138131(v=vs.118).aspx) class to modify the HTTP status code based on the error.

Example:

```
Public Class ProductController
Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim htmlUtility As HtmlUtility

    Try
        htmlUtility.LoadUrl(request.UrlToGenerateFrom)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Change status code in HTTP response.
        Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
    End Try
End Function

End Class
```